# Why is ArrayIterator subclass's constructor never called?

Tags: php, iterator

I'm baffled why a subclass to `ArrayIterator` is never getting its `__construct` method called. Consider this example:

```
<?php

class ConstructorException extends Exception {}

class Foo extends ArrayObject {
    function __construct( $arr = array(), $flags = 0, $iterator = 'ArrayIterator' ) {
        $iterator = 'FooIterator';
        parent::__construct( $arr, $flags, $iterator );
    }
}

class FooIterator extends ArrayIterator {
    function __construct( $array = array(), $flags = 0 ) {
        throw new ConstructorException( 'HELLO WORLD' ); // I AM NEVER CALLED.
        parent::__construct( $array, $flags );
    }
}

try {
    $f = new Foo( array( 1, 2, 3 ) );
    $it = $f->getIterator();
    if ( get_class( $it ) !== 'FooIterator' ) {
        throw new Exception( 'Expected iterator to be FooIterator.' );
    }
    die( "FAIL\n" );
} catch ( ConstructorException $e ) {
    die( "PASS\n" );
} catch ( \Exception $e ) {
    die( sprintf( "ERROR: %s\n", $e->getMessage() ) );
}
```

In both PHP 5.4 an 5.5, the result is `FAIL`. Why?

Comment: John Blackbourn notes that it works in HHVM: http://3v4l.org/e9qF9 /via https://twitter.com/johnbillion/status/601900452293300224

Comment: It seems an internal problem in php. [spl_array_object_new_ex](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/spl/spl_array.c#L143) don't call parent's constructor. It should be reported?

Comment: Constructors on built-in objects are a bit funky - note for instance that [SimpleXMLElement declares its constructor to be `final`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php), so that subclasses have to go through the right factory procedure. That's not true of `ArrayIterator`, though, so maybe this is just a bug.

Comment: Seems definitely like a bug to me. If you call the constructor with the object return'ed from `getIterator()` you will get the exception. But with your code not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Leggendario is right to say the problem lies in the `spl_array_object_new_ex` method. However, if it's a bug i'm not sure. It is, however, not really standard what is going on here.

The `iteratorClass` variable from the constructor (or set through `setIteratorClass`) would suggest that this class gets instantiated whenever we retrieve the iterator from the `ArrayObject`. But it does not do regular "instantiation", as this is not possible.

It will just initialize the iterator (allocate memory etc), but not call the constructor. It makes sense to not call the constructor, as the constructor of an `ArrayIterator` takes two arguments (`$array` and `$flags`), and your class might have changed its signature, maybe even adding more (mandatory values).

Normally the `ArrayIterator` (or `RecursiveArrayIterator`), are internal classes and have a internal structure attached to them (basically like its own internal set of properties which you cannot get to directly from PHP userland). The `spl_array_object_new_ex` will set these internal values directly (most notably, the `ce_get_iterator` and `ar_flags`). So basically it takes over the work of the ArrayIterator constructor.

Because PHP checks if the given class is an `ArrayIterator`, or if one of the parent classes is one. When so, it means that it ultimately it can use these internal values and thus sets them directly, bypassing any need for a constructor. As a downside, anything that you would like to construct yourself, will not be called.

Comment: Actually, I can override methods in an `ArrayIterator` subclass and they get called as expected: https://github.com/xwp/wp-customize-widgets-plus/blob/8a9cd09eae1e936378add62ddb992460649d9573/php/class-widget-settings.php#L51-L141

Comment: You can see that `offsetGet()` can be successfully overridden in all versions of PHP that have `ArrayIterator` (except 5.0.0 - 5.0.3): http://3v4l.org/tJgV5

Comment: Yes, you are right. I misread the code, and checked it with a wrong test (adding the methods to the arrayobject instead of the arrayiterator). Instead, what it does is manually copying/caching some methods over from the given class (`FooIterator`) into the internal iterator functions. Most likely to either speed up things, or because lack of "proper" initialization of the class in the first place.

Comment: @WestonRuter You added a bounty, but you won't find a better answer. JayTaph nailed it down.

Comment: Bounty went to Nicholas Vasilaki because he provided a working solution, but this answer remains accepted because it explains the underlying reason for why the class is not instantiated. (Bounty was given by my colleague.)

Answer (score 3):

Method **__construct** was called, as usually, on creating new instance:

```
$it = new FooIterator();
```

So, it take some time and I have a solution: **override method getIterator()** in your **class Foo** (subclass of ArrayObject) in your example to next:

```
class Foo extends ArrayObject {

    public function __construct( $arr = array(), $flags = 0, $iterator = 'FooIterator' ) {
        parent::__construct( $arr, $flags, $iterator );
    }

    /**
     * @return ArrayIterator
     */
    public function getIterator()
    {
        $class = $this->getIteratorClass();
        return new $class($this);
    }
}
```

With this correction your code will 'PASS'.

Result of changed code from question: http://3v4l.org/HnFQm

Previous code without exception, but showing that iterator work well with changes of method getIterator() in class Foo (adding by index and unsetting): http://3v4l.org/R8PHr

Comment: Can you adapt the code in my example to cause it to echo PASS? I want to see a demonstration for how to get `FooIterator::__construct()` actually called. This is the sole purpose of throwing the exception in my example.

Comment: @WestonRuter check this out: [link](http://3v4l.org/HnFQm) Just override function getIterator().

Comment: @WestonRuter also check this: without exception, but with iterating and unset'ing: http://3v4l.org/R8PHr

Comment: I don't see the `__construct` method being called still. See this further simplified example: https://gist.github.com/westonruter/bc6e0ba317a90046f8e4

Comment: @WestonRuter you looked at first link? Saw result? Also i wrote: "Just override function getIterator()". What are you doing? You don't take my part of the code and says 'not work yet'. If don't wanna give bounty with your friend - just wrote it. More one (and last link) with working code just as you wish, with calling of '__construct' method: http://3v4l.org/DlDOj . Is it enough?

Comment: To be honest, I haven't been able to understand your answers very well, sorry. Now I think I get it. Your solution is to just add a `getIterator()` method to the `ArrayIterator` subclass to ensure that it that explicitly instantiates the supplied iterator class, and then the constructor is called as expected. Is that right? If so, then you probably should re-word your answer to explain the solution, as I didn't get it after reading it several times.

Comment: @WestonRuter No, is'n. **Override in class Foo (subclass of ArrayObject) method getIterator()**. I thought you read my first comment, with link to the modified code, you gave in your question, which produced the answer 'PASS'. Edited my answer.